# Sort List<Object> by current month to Last six months

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am having the following data in my list:

```
    List<FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("october", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("april", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("march", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("november", 30));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("may", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("january", 53));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("december", 30));
```

**What am I trying to do?**
I am trying to sort this data in a sequence such that the data is sorted by month and the month should start from the current month and count the previous six months.
**For example**:
Currently, it is May, and the data should be sorted in the following order:

```
[MAY, APRIL, MARCH, FEBRUARY, JANUARY, DECEMBER]
```

And if any month is missing, it should simply skip it and go for the next month and should complete the count.

**What I have tried so far?**

I have tried the following code to get the current month and the preceding six months:

```
        YearMonth thisMonth = YearMonth.now();
    String[] month = new String[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        YearMonth lastMonth = thisMonth.minusMonths(i);
        DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM");
        month[i] = lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter);
        month[i] = month[i].toUpperCase();
    }

    List<String> monthList = Arrays.asList(month);
    System.out.println(monthList);
```

I have also tried writing a `Comparator` but it is not working as expected. I am a bit confused with the logic to write the `Comparator`.

```
        Comparator<FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult> comp = (o1, o2)
            -> monthList.indexOf(o2.getMonth().toUpperCase()) - monthList.indexOf(o1.getMonth().toUpperCase());
    list.sort(comp);
```

It gives the output as follows:

```
     [Feature: december Count: 30 
         , Feature: january Count: 53 
         , Feature: march Count: 46 
         , Feature: april Count: 46 
         , Feature: may Count: 46 
         , Feature: october Count: 46 
         , Feature: november Count: 30]
```

Here is the `FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult` class for reference:

```
class FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult {

private String month;
private int count;

public FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult(String feature, int count) {
    this.month = feature;
    this.count = count;
}

  public FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult() {
}
public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String feature) {
    this.month = feature;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    string.append("Feature: ").append(getMonth()).append(" Count: ").append(getCount()).append(" \n");
    return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: What if your data contains months which are in the feature or older than 6 months? Do you want to filter out those entries?

Comment: @Eritrean My data can have 12 months of data from the current month. I want to return the data of previous six months only. Rest of it can be skipped

Comment: i think the comparator is not working, because `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM")` is not returning the months with all uppercase letters. You are trying to find `MAY` in a list that contains `May`.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the full timestamp?  Sorting descending and displaying only the month is very easy, where as with this solution you need to break the list into 2 list, sort then each descending and then stick one on the other.

Comment: @thinkgruen I am converting it to upper case in the same loop.

Comment: @Ryan I am getting data from the database and after performing a number of operations, the shown one is the result that I have to return. I can not alter the whole code at the moment as a number of methods depend on that logic and changing it will break my whole code

Comment: @Ryan could you please give a hint for that? I could give that a try if it would work

Comment: Why not include the year along with month as a result of analyzing your DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
enum Month {
    JANUARY,
    FEBRUARY,
    MARCH,
    APRIL,
    MAY,
    JUNE,
    JULY,
    AUGUST,
    SEPTEMBER,
    OCTOBER,
    NOVEMBER,
    DECEMBER
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList("october", "april", "march", "november", "may", "january", "december");
    Month currentMonth = Month.MAY;
    List<String> thisYear = data.stream()
                                .filter(a -> Month.valueOf(a.toUpperCase()).ordinal() <= currentMonth.ordinal())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> lastYear = data.stream()
                                .filter(a -> Month.valueOf(a.toUpperCase()).ordinal() > currentMonth.ordinal())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Comparator<String> monthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {    
            Month mA = Month.valueOf(a.toUpperCase());
            Month mB = Month.valueOf(b.toUpperCase());
            return mB.compareTo(mA);
        }
    };
    thisYear.sort(monthComparator);
    lastYear.sort(monthComparator);
    
    thisYear.addAll(lastYear);
    System.out.println(thisYear);
}
```

Comment: by making a few more modifications, i have got it working for my use case. Thanks a lot

Comment: Java 8+ already has a `java.time.Month` enum.

Answer (score 5):

Here an alternative approach:

- Get a list of months from [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum from the `java.time` API
- Rotate the list using [`Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,int)) and current month value
- Reverse the list using [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))
- Create a comparator to compare months based on the index of above list
- Stream, sort and limit

Something like

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("october", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("april", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("march", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("november", 30));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("may", 46));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("january", 53));
    list.add(new FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult("december", 30));


    List<Month> months = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Month.values()));
    Collections.rotate(months, 12 - YearMonth.now().getMonthValue());
    Collections.reverse(months);

    Comparator<FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult> comp =
            Comparator.comparingInt(f -> months.indexOf(Month.valueOf(f.getMonth().toUpperCase())));

    list.stream().sorted(comp).limit(6).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming current month will get the integer 0 (or 11), then assign each month a consecutive int.

for example, May = 0, June = 1, .... january = 8...

then, sort your input array and from there, the problem is really easy

Comment: How is your answer different from what the OP is already doing with `monthList` (albeit it's in reverse)?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. What you're missing are 2 things:

1. You forgot to filter out months that are more than 6 months ago.
2. You got the comparison reversed (so you're seeing things in ascending instead of descending order).

The following does both filtering and sorting:

```
    Comparator<FeatureAnalyzeDTOResult> comp =
            Comparator.comparingInt(o -> monthList.indexOf(o.getMonth().toUpperCase()));
    list = list.stream()
            .filter(o -> monthList.contains(o.getMonth().toUpperCase()))
            .sorted(comp)
            .toList();
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[Feature: may Count: 46 
, Feature: april Count: 46 
, Feature: march Count: 46 
, Feature: january Count: 53 
, Feature: december Count: 30 
]
```